# How do I do this simple Ruby loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

How do I make a range from 1 through 25 and then print out only the even numbers (hint: remember modulo)? I used this as my answer:

```
(1..25).each {|n| print n % 2 == 0}
```

and got boolean values printed. I want to get the numbers instead. What do I need to change in my code above?

Comment: print n if n % 2 ==0

Answer (score 6):

```
(1..25).each{|n| puts n if n.even?}
```

or

```
puts (1..25).select(&:even?)
```

Comment: With so many answers here, it's nice to point out why we like this one best. For me it's the use of `even?` :)

Answer (score 1):

You were somewhat misunderstanding the condition

```
(1..25).each {|n| puts n if n % 2 == 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts (1..25).select {|n| n % 2 == 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts (1..25).select {|n| n.even?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def print_even(r)
  puts ((r.first.even? ? r.first : r.first+1)..r.last).step(2) { |i| puts i }
end

print_even((1..25))
  #=> 2
  #=> 4
  #=> 6
  ...
  #=> 24
print_even((2..26))
  #=> 2
  #=> 4
  #=> 6
  ...
  #=> 26
```

...and another:

```
even = true
(1..25).each { |i| puts i if (even = !even) }
```